# Nested dictionary sorting by values in sub dictionary and then length of subdictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested, subdirectory

As a newbie I'm struggling with the sorting of a nested dictionary. Lets say i have these two nested dictionaries as examples:

Example 1:

```
{'Red': {'Pesho': 2000}, 'Blue': {'Tosho': 1000}, 'Green': {'Gosho': 1000}, 'Yellow': {'Sasho': 4500}, 'Stamat': {'Prakasho': 1000}}
```

Example 2:

```
{'Red': {'Pesho': 10000}, 'Blue': {'Pesho': 10000, 'Gosho': 10000}}
```

Now I need to sort the players by points in descending order and then by total number of players within each team/color again in descending order. The print output should look like this:

For example 1: 
(Yellow) Sasho <-> 4500
(Red) Pesho <-> 2000
(Blue) Tosho <-> 1000
(Green) Gosho <-> 1000
(Stamat) Prakasho <-> 1000

For example 2:
(Blue) Pesho <-> 10000
(Blue) Gosho <-> 10000
(Red) Pesho <-> 10000

I imagine it can be done with sorted() using lambdas but cant warp my head around the exact syntax. Will be very grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first pass through an intermediate representation to associate the size the group the element belongs to the element in order to use it in the sorting.

```
>>> l2 = [(k,el,d[k][el],len(v)) for k,v in d.items() for el in v]
>>> l2
[('Red', 'Pesho', 10000, 1), ('Blue', 'Pesho', 10000, 2), ('Blue', 'Gosho', 10000, 2)]
```

and then sort with a lambda function in which the 2 comparison terms `(score, size of group)` are used.

```
>>> sorted(l2, key=lambda x:(int(x[2]),x[3]),reverse=True)
[('Blue', 'Pesho', 10000, 2), ('Blue', 'Gosho', 10000, 2), ('Red', 'Pesho', 10000, 1)]
```

Comment: If I get it right you extract the info from the nested dictionary and put it in list of tuples, where you sort the stuff out depending on the requirements. I will try it out, but wanna ask - is it possible to do it with dictionary comprehensions with a lambda going deep into the subdict. like lambda x: x[y][z] for y in dict[x] or something ??

Comment: you also need the size of the group the elements belongs to, so you need to associate it with the element somehow, a tuple, another dict, etc.

Comment: Yes I see. The solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. The idea of putting the info in another more manageable structure type crossed my mind but since I've never done it before couldn't think of such a solution. Cheers!